# How to get @StartDate - 30 in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a query that I use to generate statements that shows Amount Due for the month which is calculated based on date parameters- @StartDate and @EndDate

Included in the statement, I would like to add the Amount Due from the previous month (Previous Month's Balance owing) for a date range @StartDate - 30 to @EndDate - 30. What would be the code to run that?

**My code:**

```
set nocount on

Declare @S AS DateTime = ISNULL(@StartDate,DateAdd(d,-60,GETDATE()))
Declare @anum as nvarchar(8) = ISNULL(@panum,'25991275')
Declare @E AS DateTime = ISNULL(@EndDate,DateAdd(d,-0,GETDATE()))

SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName CustName
      ,[InvoiceNumber]
      ,[StatementDate]
      ,[NewCharges]
      ,[AmountDue]
      ,[Charges]
      ,[AccountFee]
      ,[Interest]
      ,[Payments]
      ,[Refunds]
      ,[DueDate]


FROM [StatementSummary] S
INNER JOIN Account A ON S.AccountID = A.Accountid
INNER JOIN Contact C ON A.AccountId = C.AccountId


WHERE A.AccountNumber = @anum
  AND StatementDate >= @S
  AND StatementDate <= @E

ORDER BY StatementDate DESC
```

**I was thinking of making another Dataset to run the following code:**

```
  SELECT Top 1 AcctBalance    
  FROM [FinMaster]
  WHERE AcctID = @anum  
    AND BusinessDay >= @S - 30  
    AND BusinessDay <= @E - 30

  ORDER BY AcctBalance DESC
```

How do I add the date range to back to the previous month's?

If I could add this second code as a line in the first code then I won't need to create a second dataset for my report.

Comment: Thank you. How would I put that in code?

Comment: actually should be OUTER apply and Eomonth function

Answer (score 0):

Using OUTER APPLY and EOMonth function to get the Last Month value 

 Just a logic and not using your fields

```
declare @reportdate date = getdate()

select a.*, x.field....
 from table1 A
   OUTER apply (        --- to get last month data, can be null.. similar to left outer join but in a cartesian way of display
     select b.field1, b.field2, b.... 
     from table1 B
     where 
     b.product_id = a.product_id  and
     trans_date
     between   -- between last month based on the @reportdate 
     dateadd(day,1,eomonth(dateadd(month,-2,@reportdate)))   -- or      a.trans_date
    and 
    eomonth(dateadd(month,-1,@reportdate))
    ) x
where trans_date 
  between    -- your reporting date, can be any date
  dateadd(day,1,eomonth(dateadd(month,-1,@reportdate)))
  and eomonth(@reportdate)
```